# How can I simply convert an ESQL/C file to a C file? (Embedded- SQL/C file to C file)?

Tags: c, informix, embedded-sql

I'm working on a migration project. I need to convert ESQL/C files which have .ec extension into c file on gcc. I know that ESQL/C program will create a .c file. But How can I get that?

FYI : I'm working on IBM Informix server.

Comment: Which database server?  Informix or something else?  (Note that the [tag:esql] is for Entity SQL (read the info) — it is not appropriate here.)

Comment: For an Informix `.ec` file compiled with the `esql` program (script), you can use `esql -e` to 'Preprocess only, no compilation or linking' (in sufficiently recent versions — I don't recall that option, but running just `esql` gives that information, amongst others.  If you confirm Informix as the DBMS, I'll make an answer out of the information.

Comment: Yes. working with IBM informix server only. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @emb-pro, which versions of Informix and esql/c are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** — For an Informix `.ec` file compiled with the `esql` program (script), you can use the `-e` option to 'Preprocess only, no compilation or linking'.

```
esql -e esqlcode.ec
```

This produces `esqlcode.c` from `esqlcode.ec`.  (Ignore my previous comment about 'sufficiently recent'; you won't be using a version that isn't sufficiently recent — my memory is failing once more.)

The `esql` script traditionally left the intermediate `.c` file lying around.  My ESQL/C `make` rules all remove the generated `.c` file as a separate post-compilation step:

```
.ec.o:
    ${ESQL} ${ESQLFLAGS} -c $*.ec
    ${RM_F} $*.c
```

with appropriate definitions of suffixes, macros, etc.

#### The `esql` command

Using the Informix `esql` compiler (script), you can run it with no options to get a help message like this (try not to be scared: there's actually the usages for two commands):

```
Usage: esql [-e] [-thread] [-glu] [esqlcargs] [-cc] [otherargs] [-o outfile]
            [-cp] [-onlycp] [-np] [-nup]
            [-libs] esqlfile.ec [othersrc.c...] [otherobj.o...] [-lyourlib...]

        -e         Preprocess only, no compilation or linking
        -thread    Multithread support
        -glu       Enable GLU (GLS for Unicode)
        -esqlcargs: esqlc arguments (-g, -G, -nln, -Ipathname, -nowarn, -V, -ansi,
                                    -xopen, -local, -log, -EDname, -EUname,
                                    -icheck
        -cc        Arguments after cc go to c compiler only
        otherargs: Other arguments are passed to cc
        -o         Next argument is program name
        -libs      Display the list of libraries used by esql at link time.
        -cp        Run C preprocessor before esqlc
        -onlycp    Run only the C preprocessor, no esqlc, compilation or linking
        -np        No protection of SQL keywords in SQL statements
        -nup       No unprotection of SQL keywords, forces -onlycp


Usage: esqlc [-thread] [-gG] [-nln] [-Ipathname] [-nowarn] [-V] [-ansi]
             [-static] [-xopen] [-local] [-log file] [-EDname[=val]] [-EUname]
             [-icheck] [-keepccomment] [-version] esqlfile.ec
         -thread     Multithread support
         -g          Number every line (debugging purposes)
         -G          No line number (debugging purposes; same as -nln)
         -nln        No line number (debugging purposes; same as -G)
         -Ipathname  Add pathname to include file search path
         -nowarn     Do not print warnings
         -static     Link with static libraries
         -keepccomment Allow C style comments in SQL statements.
         -version    Displays build and version information.
         -V          Print preprocessor version information
         -ansi       Perform ANSI checking
         -xopen      Perform XOPEN checking
         -local      Make cursor/statement ids local to the file
         -log file   Log error and warning messages in file
         -EDname     Define specified preprocessor name flag
          [=val]     and set it equal to 'val'
         -EUname     Undefine specified preprocessor name flag
         -icheck     Check for indicator variables
```

The usage for `esqlc` is for the 'real' preprocessor, `$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esqlc`.  The usage for `esql` is for the `esql` script itself — which is what you are primarily using.  The `esqlcargs` in the `esql` usage are the ones that are listed for `esqlc` — they're passed through by the script to the program.

This output is from ESQL/C 4.10 associated with Informix 12.10.  I won't bore you with a history of the ESQL/C version numbers.